# EPPlus: Opening Password Protected Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

When we try to open a file protected in Excel 2007, it works but when we try to open same file protected in Excel 2010, it does not work. It throws following error --

**Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bound**

The EncryptedPackageHandler gives this error on line 77:

```
Array.Copy(data, 44, text, 0, (int)HeaderSize - 34);
```

**For same file protected with Excel 2007, length of arrays are:**

EncInfo1.bin -> is an encrypted binary file of size 4KB, data 248, text 130, HeaderSize 164

**For same file protected with Excel 2010, length of arrays are:**

EncInfo1.bin -> is an un-encrypted XML file of size 5KB, data: 1057, text: 1836597018, HeaderSize: 1836597052

There are no other errors while using Excel 2010 except for this one

Library used: [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com)

Comment: What are you using to open the file?

Comment: Sorry, I am using EPPlus

Comment: For one thing, HeaderSize should be a long.  Ints (int32) only handle up to 2^32.  Why is the HeaderSize so large in the second but so small in the first?  Also, are you using Array.Copy as expected?  Here are the prototypes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx .  It appears you're trying to copy 2GBs between arrays.  There's probably a better way.
This is not my area of expertise (.NET or Excel files), but the error message seems pretty specific and is telling you what the problem probably is, so check that.

Comment: The Array copy code is EPPlus code. In the first place, the HeaderSize should not be that big

Comment: How are you encrypting it in EPPlus? We dont have issues with opening files created in EPPlus in 2010. Its probably worth including code in your question.